# I found this code and wanted to know the proper definition of the "test:" part

Tags: java

I found this code and wanted to know the proper definition of the "test:" part. I tried putting the code but it would not let me.  It is what you would use on a continue test; or break test; during a loop.

Comment: "this code"? What code? Please post the code which isn't working, and the full error. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I did not have a problem with the code.  Just needed the proper definition.

Comment: But not *showing* the code makes it hard to know exactly what you're referring to. You say you "did not have a problem with the code" but in the question you say you "tried putting the code but it would not let me" - that sounds like "having a problem with the code" to me.

Comment: Next time, please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [labelled statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.7), with the label serving the purpose of identifying the statement that would be executed after the `break` or `continue` statement is executed. It is the equivalent of a `goto`, but is more restrictive in that labels may be used only in `break` or `continue` statements.

Comment: Thanks,  knew how to use it,  just wanted its definition.  I am sure someone else will enjoy that bit of extra information.  Had a interview and realized I could program,  but my terminology was bad and could not find anything on this in specific so your the best and keep up the great work.